# For $p\ge 1$, $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$, $|x^{\frac{1}{p}}-y^{\frac{1}{p}}|^p \le |x-y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I vaguely remember seeing an inequality of the form:
$$|x^{\frac{1}{p}}-y^{\frac{1}{p}}|^p \le |x-y|$$
for $p\ge 1$, $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$.

Is this correct? If so, how is it proven? Can it be tightened at all if we know $x>1$ and $y>1$?

Comment: Does it? I must be being stupid.

Comment: Since the inequality is homogeneous, the condition $x>1$ (or $y>1$) is rather irrelevant. Basically, you need to prove that $a^p+b^p\leq (a+b)^p$ for nonnegative $a,b$ (why?). The latter is equivalent to $(t+1)^p\ge t^p+1$ for $t\geq 0$. Can you continue now?

Comment: Without loss of generality assume $x>y>0$ then your problem reduces to $|1-t|^p\leq 1-t\leq 1-t^p$ for $0<t<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, assume $x>y>0$. (If $x=y$ or $y=0$ the result is trivial. If $x<y$ then we can just swap $x$ and $y$.) Then the inequality holds if and only if:
$$x^{\frac{1}{p}} - y^{\frac{1}{p}} \le (x-y)^{\frac{1}{p}},$$
i.e. if and only if:
$$1 - \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \le  \left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$
Now for $z\in[0,1]$, $z^{\frac{1}{p}}\ge z$, thus as $\frac{y}{x},\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)\in [0,1]$:
$$\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\ge 1-\frac{y}{x}\ge 1 - \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$
Thus, the result holds.

[This is essentially just the proof given in the comment of Oliver Diaz.]